# Getting most recent date values where other column values change

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, max

I have a table that is as follows:

```
  id value  date
  ---------------
  a, test,  01-01-15
  a, test,  01-02-15
  a, test,  01-03-15
  a, test1, 01-04-15
  a, test1, 01-05-15
  b, test, 01-01-15
  b, test, 01-02-15
```

I need to write a query to be able to grab the latest mapping for both a & b

for instance, I want my results to be as follows:

```
a, test1, 01-05-15
b, test,  01-02-15
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to accomplish this

```
select max(date)
```

only returns the latest date value

and `select max(date), value group by value` obviously does not return the id column

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using

Comment: I need the ID and value columns in the results

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what version of SQL you use, you may have a function called `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` that can help.

```
WITH x AS
(SELECT id, value, date 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS RowNum
FROM table
)
SELECT id, value, date
FROM x
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

The above would work in SQL Server and anything else that supports CTE and Windowing Functions. You could also write it as a derived table like this:

SELECT id, value, date
FROM 
   (SELECT id, value, date 
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM table
   ) AS x
WHERE RowNum = 1

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports `Row_number` then use this

```
select id,value,date from 
(
select row_number() over(partition by value order by date desc) as RN,
       id,value,date
from yourtable
) A
where RN=1
```

another way is by joining the result back to the table.

```
SELECT A.id, 
       A.value, 
       A.date 
FROM   yourtable A 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(date) AS date, 
                          value 
                   FROM   yourtable 
                   GROUP  BY value) B 
               ON A.date = b.date 
                  AND A.value = B.value
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id, date DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

#### Fast

For data distributions with *many* rows per `id`:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)